# How to add openssl to qt project on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, qt-creator, lib

I can not add openssl to the qt pro file. What you need to add to the profile if the library is downloaded from the repository and is located at /usr/src? As the manual said, I moved libcrypto.o and libssl.o to the headers folder and copied the header folder to the project folder in qt. This did not work. I also tried to specify a direct path to the headers folder.

Here's what these two options look like.

```
INCLUDEPATH += openssl

LIBS += openssl/libcrypto.a -ldl -lpthread
LIBS += openssl/libssl.a
```

second

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl

LIBS += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/libcrypto.a -ldl -lpthread
LIBS += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/libssl.a
```

After that, the compiler still does not see the headers. What am I doing wrong? How to add openssl to qt project?

Comment: show the complete error message. How did you install openssl?

Comment: @eyllanesc, No error message. #include simply does not see .h files and write that the file to be added does not exist.

Comment: okay, you need to tell me how you installed openssl

Comment: @eyllanesc, from the ubuntu repository

Comment: What command or method have you used? Please be detailed in your answer. I want the necessary information to reproduce your problem and then point out a detailed solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc, sudo apt-get install openssl

Comment: okay, what version of ubuntu do you use?